# Table join yielding null values

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to import some values from two similar spreadsheets into an attribute table I have for a vector shapefile in QGIS. The table and the spreadsheets share a common field called Id_1, and the values should match. However, when I try to do a join and open up the attribute table, it brings in null values. I can't seem to find any options that I should be checking that could make a difference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As long as we don't see the attributes of both layers, it's difficult to say. Best would be posting your data -  a sample of both layers

Comment: @Babel Posted. I didn't sort them for the pics but like i said the values in the ID_1 field are exactly the same.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any trailing spaces or non printable characters in the ID_1 fields.  Sometimes they can *look* the same but be different.

Comment: Indeed. That's why best is to post a link to the original data for testing

Comment: Sorry, but in the screenshots you posted, I can't find any matching values in the two layers. You must have the same value like e.g. `T25` in `LC_Grid_2013_Ipervious` and `T25` in `LC_Grid_2013_Canopy`. If you don't have this like in your screenshot, it's logic that you don't get any results.

Comment: @babel they are all originally from the same table those values have not been edited so they should be the same. I made a copy here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nJaKS29wLJy4nUntDoRbZ60msBv2mfR4

Comment: @babel see link